# Basic authentication using ajax throws error unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, basic-authentication

I am trying to make an ajax call for the baic authentication using the following code -

```
    $.ajax({
     method: "GET",
     xhrFields: {
         "withCredentials": true
     },
     beforeSend: function (xhr) {
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic c2h1YmhhbS5hLmFncmF3YWw6U1VOSUxANzYwMg==');
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
     },
     url: //some url,
     dataType: "jsonp",
     success: function (res) {
         alert("SUCC");
     },
     error: function (err) {
         console.log(err);
         alert(err.status);
     }
 });
```

But everytime it thorows the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < and goes to the error function.

Couldn't figure out the problem....plz help....very important.!!!

Regards,
Shubham Agrawal

Comment: may be there is syntax error on the file which is called by ajax

Comment: Yes, hit the ajax url directly in the browser and check whether it runs without error.

Comment: you comment the url it also affect the comma at the end.

Comment: Instead of `method: "GET",` can you try `type: "GET",`?

Comment: Sounds like the server returns XML or HTML, but not JSONP. Check the response from the server in your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Hi @FelixKling Yes the return type is xml but if I give any data type other than jsonp....i get the cross-origin error.

Comment: Well, then *that's* the problem. JSONP is a very specific response format and it has to be supported by the server (just like XML has to be supported when you want XML). JSONP is not a silver bullet for cross-origin requests.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3076414/218196).